# Reset css or script when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be hard to explain but say my browser size is small like in image 1. The bottom text is positioned where it should be and when I scroll down a script activates.

*EDIT* https://jsfiddle.net/j4f53rds/1/

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#nav_color");
    var top = $div.data("top");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top' : top + 'px'});
    }
}

$("#nav_color").data("top", $("#nav_color").offset().top); 
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

The script causes the text on the bottom to become fixed on the top of the html as the user scrolls down. Now here comes the issue. After firing, if I resize the browser, say make it full screen, like in image two, and then scroll back up. The text doesn't reposition to it's would be new location, it resets back to the original position in the smaller browser. How do I get the script to take into account a new browser size when the user scrolls back up?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are saving off the top position when the page loads, but that position changes when the window is resized. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#nav_color").data("top", $("#nav_color").offset().top); 
    fixDiv(); //not sure if you need this.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're `top:` inline CSS property is sticking to the `#nav_color` element and is not being recalculated when you resize,

try this (variable `top` definition still isn't perfect..):

```
var top = $("#nav_color").offset().top; 

function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#nav_color");
   // var top = $div.data("top"); shouldn't define it here  
    console.log(top);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top' : top + 'px'});
    }
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);

function positionDiv() {
    top = ($(window).innerHeight())*0.86;
    if ($("#nav_color").css('position') == 'absolute'){
        $("#nav_color").css({ 'top': top });
    }

}
$(window).resize(positionDiv);
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/j4f53rds/10/)

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/j4f53rds/4/) is working as it's supposed to (as jquery processes - the listeners are executing the code in the right spot). the problem are in the code it's executing... I'm probably not fully understanding your issue but couldn't you just use CSS `bottom` property to position div on the bottom

Comment: Sorry I must not be explaining this correctly. The nav is positioned at the bottom of the viewport at page load, however, when you scroll down it will touch the top of the page and "stick" there and fix itself as the scroll continues. When you scroll back to the top of the page, it will "unstick" itself and go back to the bottom of the viewport. This (https://jsfiddle.net/j4f53rds/3/) is what its supposed to do normally. But the problem arises when a browser is resized.

Comment: Hmm. The issue still comes up. When you grow the 'results' section of the fiddle and scroll to the bottom and then to the top, it doesn't repoisition itself to the new browser size. Press run again to see where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function on `window.resize`
You can call your function like :

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    $("#nav_color").data("top", $("#nav_color").offset().top()); 
    fixDiv(); //not sure if you need this.
});
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite getting it correct for some reason. :(

Comment: @user2252219 sorry don't get you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$addHandler(window, "resize", fixDiv);
```

Each time a user resize the window, the funcion fixDiv will be triggered

Comment: I gave that a go but :(. I updated OP with a fiddle.