# Adding a window.resize function to let script reset on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be hard to explain but say my browser size is small like in image 1. The bottom text is positioned where it should be and when I scroll down a script activates.

What it's supposed to do (sticky div to top): https://jsfiddle.net/j4f53rds/3/

What I've got it now (I tried adding the following code)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
$("#nav_color").data("top", $("#nav_color").offset().top); 
fixDiv(); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4f53rds/2/

This is the original code :

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#nav_color");
    var top = $div.data("top");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#nav_color').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top' : top + 'px'});
    }
}

$("#nav_color").data("top", $("#nav_color").offset().top); 
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

The script causes the text on the bottom to become fixed on the top of the html as the user scrolls down. Now here comes the issue. After firing, if I resize the browser, say make it full screen, like in image two, and then scroll back up. The text doesn't reposition to it's would be new location, it resets back to the original position in the smaller browser. How do I get the script to take into account a new browser size when the user scrolls back up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset css or script when brower is resized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545307/reset-css-or-script-when-brower-is-resized)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this way:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/zd33svjs/)

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I must not be explaining this correctly. The nav is positioned at the bottom of the viewport at page load, however, when you scroll down it will touch the top of the page and "stick" there and fix itself as the scroll continues. When you scroll back to the top of the page, it will "unstick" itself and go back to the bottom of the viewport.